# Auto rejoin domain

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to automate the process of rejoining the computer in domain when it loses trust with domain.
Can somebody help me with that so without leaving the desk I can rejoin the computer in domain by running any powershell script?

Comment: https://dirteam.com/tomek/2007/01/08/how-to-remove_5c00_add-workstation-from_5c00_to-domain-remotely_3f00_/

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).